# How to allow on 12 digits or less than 12 digits with only decimals using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox field where i need to allow 18 or less than 18 digits and not more than 2 decimals (it may be 1 or 2 but not more than two).How can i do this

Totally 18 digits before decimal and 
two digits after decimal

```
<input type="text" name="Txtpercentage"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
$("input[name='Txtpercentage']").on('keydown', function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    //alert(key);
    if (!([8, 9, 13, 27, 46, 110, 190,17,86].indexOf(key) !== -1 ||
            (key == 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
            (key >= 48 && key <= 57 && !(e.shiftKey || e.altKey)) ||
            (key >= 96 && key <= 105)
        )) e.preventDefault();

            if ($(this).val().length >= 12) {
        var thisVal = $(this).val();
        var valtoIns = thisVal.substring(0, 15);
        $(this).val(valtoIns);
        if (!([8].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    }
});
$("input[name='Txtpercentage']").on('keypress', function(e) {
 var regex = /\.\d{2,}/;
 var isTwoDecimal = regex.test($(this).val());
 //alert(isTwoDecimal);
 if(isTwoDecimal){
    e.preventDefault();
 }
});
```

See working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuaibkhan1911/zj724tL8/14/)

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi I need to allow 18 digits and a decimal and two digits after decimal can you please let me know how to acheive this

Comment: 18 digits (including decimal and two digits?)